# How to tackle a page with fixed vertical and horizontal navigation

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, navigation

I linked a Jpeg to this request to better illustrate my questions (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7gjrjsUBWeTTDA1S1JpeFAwWFE/view?usp=sharing). I am fairly new at CSS and html and I want to push myself (something I am doing for fun). I am making a dashboard similar to your GMAIL inbox, using Skeleton Boilerplate.

I will have a main header (menu) which I already made. What I am trying to figure out now is what to do with the vertical navigation and the second header?

Do I make the vertical nav a list? How do a line up the 2nd header to the right of the vertical nav? I guess I am just looking for strategy. Sorry, about this being such a noob question. Any input would help.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5pLtpfr3/)</kbd>

For google-friendly SEO, enclose the nav inside `<nav></nav>` tags, and use anchor tags for the menu items, whether inside list structure or not:

```
<ul><li><a html="#">Menu Item</a></li></ul>
```

Break your page up into chunks, using DIVs. Put every discreet *section* (block? part?) into DIVs. Or, use Twitter's [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (which does the same thing).

Something like this:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
    </div><!-- #header -->
    <nav id="sideNav">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
        </ul>
    </nav><!-- #sideNav -->
    <div id="subhead">
    </div><!-- #subhead -->
    <div id="container">
        <article>
        </article>
    </div><!-- #container -->
</div><!-- #wrap>
</body>
```

---

To make the nav menu `<li>` items side by side, you would use:

```
ul li {display:inline;}
```

To style the navigation to the left, with subheader and content to the right, something like the following will get you started:

```
#wrap {width:100%;}
#header  {width:100%;height:80px;}
#sideNav {float:left;width:15%;min-height:500px;}
#subHead {margin-left:15%;width:85%;height:80px;}
#container {margin-left:15%;width:85%;min-height:500px;}
```

When using `float`, it is important to understand that `float:left` (or right) will remove the DIV from the page flow. This is how the `subHead` and `container` are positioned beside the `sideNav`. However, when using floats, following DIVs could be on top of the floated divs. *(See the section The Great Collapse in the *all-about-floats* link below)* Therefore, you must know about "clearing the float" at the parent level:

```
#wrap {width:100%;overflow:auto;}
```

There is more, but this will get you started.

Or, learn [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), which does a lot of this for you ***and*** makes sure your site is mobile-friendly (aka "responsive").

References:

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/